# C# cannot create windows service that will start

Tags: c#, windows, service

I'm trying to write my first Windows Service in C#. If I follow the MS tutorial to the letter, I can create a simple service with a timer that works and writes to the eventLog. The second I change ANYTHING it will not start with 1064. 
I installed the service by calling C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe from the solution's bin\debug folder. 
I have uninstalled the service and reinstalled it.
I have used SC DELETE and reinstalled it.
I have rebooted. Nothing works, unless I start a new project from scratch,  which fails again when I try to change anything. Does something have to be reset if you change code?

Comment: What does it mean The second I change ANYTHING?

Comment: Would be helpful if you could create a [mcve]

Comment: What if we change anything and it works? We really need to know *what specific things* you're trying.

Comment: ANYTHING from changing the service name to changing the text in the eventlog message  to adding a class or adding some code

Comment: minimal reproducible example = MS Tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer this works, so long as I don't change anything like service name or code

Comment: I just recreated the service from scratch , installed it, it worked. I uninstalled it, changed the displayname reinstalled it and now it fails to start. I have the original source preserved

Comment: If the original source is used, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Starting again with baby steps and careful use of the event log I was able to determine that the service could not access a file path which referred to a drive created with a SUBST command (I don't have an E drive on the development machine). I presume this is because the SUBST is not in the service's process, however why that caused the service controller to error on startup I don't know, possibly because the path was accessed from Properties.Settings.Default. The mystery fact remains that a working version stopped working when I only changed the service display name and rebuilt (after uninstalling & reinstalling).